# Connect to IPv6 SSH server

Tags: ssh, putty, ipv6

I'm currently facing a problem I don't have enough knowledge to solve. I've to connect to a SSH server which only supports IPv6 addresses but the problem is my network only supports IPv4 addresses. Is there any way I can bypass this or do I have 0 chances to connect to the server? Thanks for your time

Comment: You might be able to use a VPN service that supports IPv6. I don't know which ones support connecting to the VPN server over IPv4 and then making IPv6 connections out to the internet. Unfortunately, most of the discussion of IPv6 support I've seen is about connecting to the VPN server over IPv6 (which is irrelevant for your situation).

Comment: Aside from the vg answer and comment given, pester your (I assume) isp to support ipv6. There's really no excuse not to.

Answer (score 1):

You need an IPv6 "tunnel" (a.k.a. VPN) that provides your local computer (or whole local network) with IPv6 connectivity.

While it is usually outside the scope of SuperUser to recommend specific products, I know many people (myself included) who have been using [Hurricane Electric Tunnelbroker](https://tunnelbroker.net/) for exactly this purpose for many years.

I am sure there are other providers that provide IPv6 over a VPN, but I can't name them off the top of my head.